# Connection pooling with SQL driver in Go

Tags: sql, go

What is the best practice for storing a connection to a database in Go language?

In Java for example you can use singletons, some IoC containers like Spring.
What is the best practice in it's lifecycle?
How to release it after application close?

Answer (score 13):

There is nothing wrong about using a Singleton pattern here too.

I would use something like this:

```
var db *sql.DB = nil

func GetDB() (*sql.DB, error) {
    if db == nil {
        conn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=require",
            DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
        log.Println("Creating a new connection: %v", conn)

        d, err := sql.Open("postgres", conn)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        db = d
    }

    return db, nil
}
```

With this exported function you can receive a connection from all other packages.

*Update of the answer according to the comments (thanks @all for the information)!:*

> The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and
>   maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function
>   should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB.[¹](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open)
>
> It is rare to Close a DB, as the DB handle is meant to be long-lived
>   and shared between many goroutines.[²](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Close)

I would say that there is no forcing reason to call close on the database connection. I found no other statements. Despite this I would use a `defer GetDB().close()` in the `main` function - just for the completeness of the code.

Another thing I would like to note is that the connection should be verified by a `db.Ping()` otherwise the connection could be established but the database may not exist.

With this new information I wouldn't bother using some mutexes to ensure that the database is established. I would create a new `DBInit()` and run it inside the `init()` function of the main package.

Comment: Support I get connection pool in some func by calling sql.Open - how should I store it inside my application.

Comment: What is the common approach here? I'm not asking about ways to persists data - but a way yo store reference to connection pool in application.

Comment: Because creation connection pool for every select isn't correct solution

Comment: Since the DB returned is concurrent safe why do you suggest a mutex?

Comment: @saarrrr The idea behind the mutex was that another thread might close the connection and there could be a race condition when I try to access the `db` variable. Am I wrong in this case?

Comment: @Mark From the docs, "The returned DB is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines and maintains its own pool of idle connections. Thus, the Open function should be called just once. It is rarely necessary to close a DB."  Perhaps we should just say it is a bad idea to close the DB at all, just let the connection pool do its thing and worry about the transactions, not the connection.  More importantly, db.Close() closes the database, not the connection.  https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Open

Comment: @Mark I saw that using sync.Once maybe solve this thing better.I guess closing DB will close connection pool, but not connections (Is there are documentation saying that closing connection is must?)

Comment: @AndreMinov as I mentioned you could add a `defer GetDB().close()` function in your `main` function. It will close the connection if your program ends The driver manages the connection pool. Do you have any further question or anything else I should update in my question?

Comment: @Mark thank you for answer! Everything is clear now.